# cURL hangs on request, waits for timeout to proceed

Tags: php, curl

I'm encountering a problem to which I can't find a solution anywhere. Even worse, none else seems to have this problem so I'm probably doing something very stupid.

Some background info: I'm trying to make a proxy-like page that forwards an AJAX request to a different server. This to circumvent the same-domain-policy. All I want this code to do is take the POST variables, forward them to a different page, and then return the results. It's been working but for 1 thing: every time it waits for the timeout to continue. I've put it to 1 second now, so it's doing ok for now, but I'd rather have a fast response and proper timeout.

Here's my code:

```
// create a new cURL resource
$call = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($call, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($call, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($call, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($call, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($call, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($call, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$response = curl_exec($call);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($call);

echo $response;
```

I've tried sending a "Connection: close" header with it, and several ways to make the target code specify that it's done running (setting Content-length, flushing, die(), etc.). At this point I really don't know what's going on, what surprises me most is that I can't find anyone with a similar problem.

Who can help me?

Comment: Hmm, strange that you describe it as waiting for the timeout, the timeout is meant to be a maximum value. What is the applications behavior if no timeout is specified (Or if you specify 0 as the value)?

Comment: I haven't tried it with 0 as timeout value yet, but without a specified timeout it takes about 15 seconds, which I guessed is a default of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

This would make sense if the server weren't actually completing the request. This would be expected in a page streaming or service streaming scenario. Are you sure that the server is actually returning a full and complete HTTP response to each request?

Comment: I think so, calling the page directly from the browser doesn't create any problem. I'll have a look into it though, there might be an issue there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's trying to connect, timing out, and the retry is working.

This fixed it for me:

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

I *can* connect on the commandline via ipv6, so I don't know why this helps.